# alternative definition of analytic functions

Tags: complex-analysis

**Definition**: A map $f : U → V$ between open subsets $U ⊂ \mathbb C^n, V ⊂\mathbb C^m$ is called complex differentiable if it is (totally) differentiable in the sense of real analysis and if the Jacobi map $J(f, a) : \mathbb C^n → \mathbb C^m $ is $\mathbb C$-linear for all $a ∈ U$.

We know that  $f(z)=|z|^2$ is not analytic anywhere. Where in the real sense $f(x,y)=x^2+y^2$ is differentiable and the Jacobi matrix $J= \begin{pmatrix} 2x&&0\\ 0&& 2y \end{pmatrix}$. Why $J$ is not $\mathbb C$-linear for any $z\in \mathbb C$.

Comment: you know that a complex number $a+ib$ is naturally represented by the $2\times 2$ real matrix $\begin{pmatrix} a&b\\ -b& a \end{pmatrix}$

Comment: Do you have notions of "complex differentiable" and "analytic" mixed up?

Comment: @ user1952009 so my $J$ in the question is not correct? maybe i dont understansd what the meant of $C$-linear, is it $J(az_1+bz_2)=aJ(z_1)+bJ(z_2)$ for all complex numbers $z_1,z_2$??

Comment: @zhw. are they different?

Comment: You used these terms. Not sure why you used both.

Comment: let $f : \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$, then the Taylor $1$ expansion at $\begin{pmatrix}x_0 \\ y_0\end{pmatrix}$ is $f(\begin{pmatrix}x_0+x \\ y_0+y\end{pmatrix}) = f(\begin{pmatrix}x_0 \\ y_0\end{pmatrix}) + J_{x_0} \times\begin{pmatrix}x \\ y\end{pmatrix}+ o(|x|+|y|)$ and we are interested in the linearity of the application $\begin{pmatrix}x \\ y\end{pmatrix} \mapsto J_{x_0} \times\begin{pmatrix}x \\ y\end{pmatrix}$. It is clearly $\mathbb{R}$-linear, but it is $(\mathbb{R}^2,+,\times) \simeq \mathbb{C}$ linear if and only if $J_{x_0}$ is of the form I wrote above

Comment: so the details are : how do you make $\mathbb{R}^2$ a field isomorphic to the complex numbers ? is $u \mapsto J_{x_0}  \times u$  $\ \ (\mathbb{R}^2,+,\times)$-linear ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a real map, $f(x,y) = (x^2 + y^2,0).$ So actually

$$J= \begin{pmatrix} 2x&&2y\\ 0&& 0 \end{pmatrix}.$$

Check that this is not $\mathbb C$-linear (except at $(0,0))$ by looking at its action on $i=(0,1).$